# ping NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at ...>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, asmx, zeep

I am very new to wsdl, asmx, client, [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) and other topics related to SOAP APIs, and I have to fix a system of "REST, SOAP APIs - service", made in Python by others.

Currently I am working only on my local machine. This is the main context:

In my project main folder `myservice` there are:

- a service made with Tornado, `myservice > myserviceSrv.py`, and
- a set of APIs whose logic is split into two scripts:

  - `myservice > handlers > myservice_api.py`: containing classes inerithing from `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, which contain `post`s methods calling the SOAP APIs in the `externalcompany_myservice_api.py` script.
  - `myservice > handlers > externalcompany_myservice_api.py`: containing a single class which contains the SOAP APIs methods that will call the externalcompany service SOAP APIs.

    One of these methods is `ping`, and my aim is to make it work, that is, I want it to get the correct response when I launch a post with Postman.
    In particular, the POST request from Postman should trigger the `ping` method of my service that should trigger the `ping` SOAP API that should trigger the corresponding SOAP API of the externalcompany service, which should answer back and in the end give me the post response.
- A module containing some configurations `myservice > config.py`, mainly the ones bound to `tornado.options`, the wsdl files path, and the APIs urls.

This is the problem:

I start my server(/service) and then I lauch the POST with Postman to `http://localhost:30205/service/ping` (with no inputs), but this is the log and traceback that I get:

```
[I 2021-11-15 10:37:20.964 myserviceSrv:76] **************************************************
[I 2021-11-15 10:37:20.964 myserviceSrv:77] Starting externalcompany service 2021-11-15 10:37:20 on port 30205 for destination externalcompany
[I 2021-11-15 10:37:20.964 myserviceSrv:78] **************************************************
[I 2021-11-15 10:33:21.354 myserver_api:154] S - post Ping Handler    
[I 2021-11-15 10:33:21.354 myserver_api:158] Destination Ping Handler: externalcompany    
[I 2021-11-15 10:33:21.354 externalcompany_myserver_api:23] S - initialise wsdl    
[W 2021-11-15 10:33:22.833 soap:218] Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS    
[W 2021-11-15 10:33:22.833 soap:218] Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS    
[I 2021-11-15 10:33:22.834 externalcompany_myserver_api:26] Created wsdl externalcompany connection    
[I 2021-11-15 10:33:22.834 externalcompany_myserver_api:27] E - initialise wsdl    
[E 2021-11-15 10:35:33.348 externalcompany_myserver_api:216] Exception error ping: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.90.XXX.YY', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /WebServices/Api/SalesApi.asmx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a5dfc4cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))    
[I 2021-11-15 10:35:33.348 web:2239] 200 POST /service/ping (::1) 131994.51ms
```

and here are my questions:

1. I don't understand where that IP address 10.90.XXX.YY comes from. I can't find a reference to it into my entire project folder.
2. It looks like the code manages to initialize the wsdl, but then it cannot establish a connection. But why? What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Here is the content of:

### myservice_api.py:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
import json
import logging
import config as config

class Ping(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, **kwargs):
        self.destination = kwargs["destination"]

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        logging.info('S - post Ping Handler')
        response = {}

        # Data received
        logging.info("Destination Ping Handler: {}".format(self.destination))

        # Init module with correct destination - start specific method ping()
        try:
            # calls the class associated to key "destination" -> the class ("externalcompanymyserviceApi") is initialized
            # init_wsdl is passed the wsdl sales file for settings
            destination_object_init = config.destination_schema[self.destination]()
            response = yield destination_object_init.ping()

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Error Ping Handler: {}".format(e))

        raise gen.Return(self.write(response))
```

### externalcompany_myservice_api.py:

```
import logging
import config as config
import json
import os
from tornado import gen
from zeep import Client, Settings, helpers
from zeep.exceptions import Fault, Error
from utils import utilities as utils

class externalcompanymyserviceApi:
    def __init__(self):
        # Init wsdl object for all methods in class externalcompany - utilities object
        self.wsdl_object_sales = self.init_wsdl(config.WSDL_SALES)

    # wsdl object
    @staticmethod
    def init_wsdl(type_wsdl):
        logging.info("S - initialise wsdl")
        settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
        wsdl_externalcompany = Client(wsdl=type_wsdl, settings=settings)
        logging.info("Created wsdl externalcompany connection")
        logging.info("E - initialise wsdl")
        return wsdl_externalcompany
```

### config.py

```
from tornado.options import define, parse_command_line
import logging
from handlers.externalcompany_myservice_api import externalcompanymyserviceApi

# LOGGING
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname)1.1s %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(module)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%F %T')

# OPTIONS

# default: ip address of externalcompany (alias of externalcompany)
define("destination", default="externalcompany", help="destination of service", type=str)

# default: port of cash service intermediating with externalcompany
define("http_port", default=30205, help="run on the given port", type=int)

parse_command_line()

# SERVICE SETTINGS
DEBUG = True

######
# WSDL
######

# links to externalcompany test server
WSDL_PRODUCTS = "https://externalcompanyapi.vendorcompany.com/webservices/productservice_v1.asmx?WSDL"
WSDL_SALES = "https://externalcompanyapi.vendorcompany.com/WebServices/Api/SalesApi.asmx?WSDL"

# HANDLERS
PING = r"/service/ping"
# ...

destination_schema = {
    "externalcompany": externalcompanymyserviceApi,
    "John": "init class John"
}
```

### myserviceSrv.py:

```
import config as cf
from config import PING
import logging
import tornado.web
from datetime import datetime
from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging
from tornado.options import options
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import httpserver

from handlers.myservice_api import Ping
#...

enable_pretty_logging()

class Destination_Service_Srv:

    def __init__(self):
        app = self.make_app()
        self.http_server = self.make_server(app)

    @staticmethod
    def make_app():
        settings = {
            "debug": cf.DEBUG
        }

        return tornado.web.Application([
            # ...
            (PING, Ping, {"destination": options.destination})
        ], **settings)

    @staticmethod
    def make_server(app):
        http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(app, decompress_request=True)
        http_server.listen(options.http_port)
        return http_server

    def start(self):
        io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        io_loop.start()

    def stop(self):
        io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        io_loop.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    myservice_server = Destination_Service_Srv()

    try:
        logging.info('**************************************************')
        logging.info('Starting myservice service {} on port {} for destination {}'.format(today, options.http_port,
                                                                                          options.destination))
        logging.info('**************************************************')
        myservice_server.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        myservice_server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Turns out that the URLs stored inside variables `WSDL_PRODUCTS` and     `WSDL_SALES` are wrong, because I can't access the corresponding wsdl files from my browser.

So I found out that the correct URLs are `HTTP://` and not `HTTPS://`

```
WSDL_PRODUCTS = "http://externalcompanyapi.vendorcompany.com/webservices/productservice_v1.asmx?WSDL"
WSDL_SALES = "http://externalcompanyapi.vendorcompany.com/WebServices/Api/SalesApi.asmx?WSDL"
```

Now my post gets the corrrect response:

```
{"ping": {"MessageNo": 1001, "MessageText": "Ping Response", "MessageInfo": "Response from 'START' on '16/11/2021
10:20:31'", "IsSuccess": true, "Content": null}}
```

---

So, to answer my own questions:

1. The IP address 10.90.XXX.YY comes from the wsdl file whose URL is saved in `WSDL_SALES`.
2. **If I get it right**,
    zeep initialized the wsdl, but it did it following the HTTPS protocol, so that the traceback indicated

   `[W 2021-11-15 10:33:22.833 soap:218] Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS`
   `[W 2021-11-15 10:33:22.833 soap:218] Forcing soap:address location to HTTPS`

   and so the connection was configured for the invalid wsdl URL.
   This was the line failing

   `zeep_response = helpers.serialize_object(self.wsdl_object_sales.service.Ping())`

   because the POST could not get a response, so the zeep serializer could not process an empty response.